# Where / how are the results stored for AsyncResult and Futures?

Tags: java, soap, asynchronous

In my understanding:

A user polls the future object until the result is available. On the other end, the job is executed synchronously and the result should be stored somewhere until next poll. Where is the result stored?

How does it happen for remote calls i.e., Async SOAP operations? For how long are the results 'stored' on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is stored in the Future object itself. It's not stored at server-side.

Thread 1 submits a Callable to an Executor. This executor creates a Runnable which implements Future and which wraps the callable and its future result. It returns this future.

Thread 2 from the executor executes the runnable future. When run, the future executes its wrapped callable, and stores the result of the callable in its result field.

Thread 1 asks the result from the future, and the future returns the result it has stored in its result field.

Look at the source code and documentation of java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.

Comment: So it means that for a remote SOAP call: the result will be on serverside in memory, until Client polls again. Meanwhile, if server crashes result is lost.

Comment: I said in my answer that the result is not stored at server-side, but iun the future itself. re-read my answer. While the async call is not executed, there is no result anywhere. Once the async call is executed, the server remote call is performed, the result is downloaded immediately, and stored in the future. When the main thread asks the future for its result, the future returns the result it has stored.